# Получение короткой ссылки из виджета

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Во внутренней программе есть виджет Яндекс карт. При просмотре адреса ты переходишь по ссылке "открыть в Яндекс картах", потом нажимаешь кнопку "поделиться" и видишь короткую ссылку.

Можно ли получить короткую ссылку из виджета? Или каким образом можно построить скрипт для получения короткой ссылки без перехода на карты в браузере?

Comment: Логичный вопрос - зачем? Если у вас генерируется ссылка на карту с объектами или маршрутом, не должно быть проблемы использовать публичные методы сокращения ссылок. Если виджет готовится вручную, там и так генерируется короткая ссылка. В чём смысл затеи?

Comment: пока что, ссылка генерируется в виде https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?from=api-maps&ll=37.622503%2C55.790233&mode=routes&origin=jsapi_2_1_79&rtext=~55.790280%2C37.627160&rtt=auto&ruri=~&z=15 это не удобно для клиентов бизнеса, нужно добавить кнопку, для генерации коротких ссылок в виде https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CDF6NJyl. Поэтому и спрашиваю о таком функционале

Comment: О том и пишу: если у вас ссылки генерируются автоматикой, в чём проблема подключить для их сокращения тот же API https://clck.ru/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Публичных методов сокращения ссылок так, как это делает [Карта](https://yandex.ru/maps) через кнопку «Поделиться», не существует. Используйте универсальные сервисы. Например, упомянутый [clck.ru](https://clck.ru/)